# Add a new menu item in the Taskbar menu of all open applications in Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7

I want to know whether it's possible to add a menu item to the taskbar right-click menu of all open applications in Windows 7. I specifically want to know whether it's possible to add the new item directly above the "Close Window" (or "Close All Windows") menu item.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect to get a down vote for asking such question! Seems like a very legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 4):

No. Imagine if that were possible: Everybody would abuse it by adding their app to the menu of every other app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually I disagree that it shouldn't be possible. There are legitimate uses for that as well, like adding a "Maximize All Windows" menu item (which is basically what I'm trying to do). If that option was possible and an application abused it, I'd simply just uninstall it.

Comment: Your trust in other applications is commendable. The Windows team, on the other hand, is far more suspicious of application developers' motives and decided not to offer the feature for fear it would be abused. (See for example, the top of the Windows XP start menu, or your Internet Explorer Favorites list.)

Comment: If I didn't trust 'some' applications, I wouldn't have any applications installed on my computer :) Your best security measure (regardless of how good your AV software is), is to only install applications you trust on your computer. Instead of removing that option completely, they could've done something like prompting the user if an application tries to modify the taskbar menu of other applications. Don't throw out the baby with the bath water :)

Comment: There's no point discussing this. The answer to the question is that it is not possible.

Comment: What about modifying the assembly code of explorer.exe? If you have admin access and enough programming skills, there is nothing stopping you from modifying whatever you want in the system... Right?

Comment: @FrankEinstein If you're willing to break the bounds of the question, then go ahead and elevate to administrator and reformat the hard drive and install a hacked version of Windows 7. If you start patching system binaries, then what you're running isn't Windows 7 any more.